# Parse JSON in Ext JS 4 or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I have this type of [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON):

```
{"value":[{"idProductCategoryAttributeValue":43,"value":"7","sortOrder":0}]}
```

I want the individual parameters values like. How do I parse this JSON string in [Ext JS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext_JS) 4 or in simple JavaScript?

Answer (score 11):

Have a look at http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.JSON. There you find how you can parse JSON with Ext JS 4.

```
var strJson = '{"value": [{"idProductCategoryAttributeValue":43,"value":"7","sortOrder":0}]}';
var obj = Ext.JSON.decode(strJson);
```

Comment: May want to escape your quotes in the `strJson` definition.

Answer (score 5):

```
var obj = Ext.decode(jsonstr);
```

Comment: This is just a shorthand for Ext.JSON.decode(). The answer is also in a lower quality then the first one (no text, no reference)